# UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseJTwain in java.library.path

Tags: java, image-scanner

I'm going to scan doc with my app which uses JTwain library for that process. but now its give this error.
are there any other requirement to 
1. add dll files 
2. add running path 
3. add argument variable on my run configuration window.?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseJTwain in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.asprise.util.jtwain.SourceManager.init(SourceManager.java:222)
    at com.asprise.util.jtwain.SourceManager.<init>(SourceManager.java:36)
    at com.asprise.util.jtwain.SourceManager.instance(SourceManager.java:28)
    at com.bellvantage.docscanner.util.DocScaner.scanDoc(DocScaner.java:58)
    at com.bellvantage.docscanner.util.DocScaner.run(DocScaner.java:49)
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.
thanks

here shows my code

```
import com.bellvantage.docscanner.domain.ScannedDoc;
import com.asprise.util.jtwain.JTwainException;
import com.asprise.util.jtwain.Source;
import com.asprise.util.jtwain.SourceManager;
import com.bellvantage.docscanner.Infrastructure.ScannedDocDAO;
import com.bellvantage.docscanner.domain.DocScanUser;
import com.bellvantage.docscanner.domain.DocumentGroup;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * 
 * @author JinathN
 * @Created On Dec 11, 2009
 */
public class DocScaner extends Thread {

    Source scanerSource;
    private DocScanListener docScanListener;
    private DocumentGroup dg;
    DocScanUser user;
    ScannedDocDAO scannedDocDAO;
    public Logger logger= Logger.getLogger(DocScaner.class);

    public DocScaner(DocumentGroup dg, DocScanUser user) {
        this.dg = dg;
        this.user = user;
        scannedDocDAO = new ScannedDocDAO();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        scanDoc();
    }

    private void scanDoc() {
        try {
            BufferedImage image;
            BufferedImage imgPrev;
            synchronized (SourceManager.class) {
                //scanerSource = SourceManager.instance().selectSourceUI();
                scanerSource = SourceManager.instance().getDefaultSource();
                if (scanerSource != null) {
                    scanerSource.setUIEnabled(false);
                    scanerSource.setAutoFeed(true);
                    scanerSource.setFeederEnabled(true);
                    scanerSource.setClearBuffers(MAX_PRIORITY);
                    scanerSource.setClearPage(true);

                    if (scanerSource != null) {
                        docScanListener.scaningStarted();
                        ScannedDoc scannedDoc;
                        do {
                            System.out.println("After While loop");
                            try {
                                image = scanerSource.acquireImageAsBufferedImage();
                                //scanerSource.acquireImage();
                                if (image != null) {
                                    imgPrev = getImgPreview(image);
                                    scannedDoc = saveDoc(image, dg, user);
                                    docScanListener.previewFound(imgPrev, scannedDoc.getId());
                                    scannedDoc = null;
                                    System.out.println("Assigned Doc to  null");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                               logger.error(e);
                               continue;
                            }
                        } while (scanerSource.hasMoreImages());
                    }
                    scanerSource.close();
                    docScanListener.scaningFinished();
                    System.out.println("Final step");
                }
                SourceManager.closeSourceManager();
                System.out.println("Source closed");
            }
        } catch (JTwainException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    private ScannedDoc saveDoc(BufferedImage image, DocumentGroup dg, DocScanUser user) {
        ScannedDoc doc = new ScannedDoc();
        doc.setDoc(getByteArray(image));
        doc.setDocumentGroup(this.dg);
        doc.setScanedUser(this.user);
        doc.setStatus("PENDING");
        doc.setScanedTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        doc.setBranch(ScanerSession.getBo()== null ? "": ScanerSession.getBo().getBranchName());
        scannedDocDAO.insert(doc);
        doc.setDoc(null);
        return doc;
    }

    private BufferedImage getImgPreview(BufferedImage sourceImage) {
        BufferedImage biPreview = null;
        double previewRatio = 80.0d / 450.0d;

        System.out.println("Ratio=" + previewRatio);
        System.out.println("w=" + sourceImage.getWidth());
        System.out.println("h=" + sourceImage.getHeight());

        int w = (int) (sourceImage.getWidth() * previewRatio);
        int h = (int) (sourceImage.getHeight() * previewRatio);

        System.out.println("w=" + w + "  h=" + h);

        biPreview = getCompatibleImage(w, h);
        Graphics2D graphics2D = biPreview.createGraphics();

        double xScale = (double) w / sourceImage.getWidth();
        double yScale = (double) h / sourceImage.getHeight();
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(xScale, yScale);
        graphics2D.drawRenderedImage(sourceImage, at);
        graphics2D.dispose();
        return biPreview;
    }

    private BufferedImage getCompatibleImage(int w, int h) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
        BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h);
        return image;
    }

    public void setPreviewListener(DocScanListener previewListener) {
        this.docScanListener = previewListener;
    }

    /*private byte[] getByteArray1(BufferedImage image) {
    byte[] img=null;
    try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(os);
    encoder.encode(image);
    img=os.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    } catch (ImageFormatException ex) {

    }
    return img;
    }*/

    private byte[] getByteArray(BufferedImage image) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = null;
        byte[] content = null;
        try {            
            os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", os);
            content = os.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        } finally {
            try {
                os.close();
                image = null;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                logger.error("getByteArray " + ex);
            }
        }
        return content;
    }

    public void deleteDocument(Long id) {
        ScannedDoc delDoc = new ScannedDoc();
        delDoc.setId(id);
        new ScannedDocDAO().delete(delDoc);
    }

    public void setDg(DocumentGroup dg) {
        this.dg = dg;
    }
}
```

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkError means missing appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native. Please check if you have added all the required dlls.

Comment: thanks dear friend.what is ur suggest dll files for my application.?
(code added) :-)

Comment: thanks i did it...
its need JTwain dll file & i put  it in my sys32 folder

Comment: Either you set java.library.path correctly or you put the AspriseJTwain.dll in the System32 folder